# Avoid Flickering on a dialog that moves its controls on resize

Tags: c++, mfc, flicker, cdialog

I have a popup dialog( `CDialog` ) that handles `WM_CTLCOLOR` message to color itself. It is having some controls (like bitmap buttons) that draws themselves using OwnerDraw. It is also having a control that displays an image with size that takes up to 70% of the dialog.

When user re-sizes the dialog, some of the controls in the dialog should be **re-positioned (not re-sized)**. *It also involves re-sizing of the image inside the dialog.* As the re-sizing of image makes the whole process slow, individual re-positioning of the controls are causing a visual effect of flickering.

I need to get rid of these. One idea is to put the controls as the children of an intermediate dialog that is the child of the original popup dialog. So, when there is a re-size, I can re-position the dialog only instead of moving each controls individually. (Re-position happens only in one direction (x *or* y), so moving the intermediate dialog should be enough.

As it involves some coding effort, before going this way, I need answers to the following questions:

- Will this work?
- If yes, whats the complexity involved in this method?
- Is there a better way?

Please help!

Comment: i dont have any experience with mfc, but flickering is usually indicative of thread safety issues. your widgets aren't thread safe and so you need to handle this appropriately. for a swing example of what i mean, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524786/how-to-close-a-frame-when-button-clicks/4524880#4524880

Comment: No Dhruv, MFC is not Swing.  Windows flickers almost always because some combination of WM_* flags is improperly set.  In my case, I needed to enable WM_CLIPCHILDREN on the parent window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably work, but you should try solutions that don't alter your control hierarchy before, because it has other subtle consequences (focus, tab order, message notifications, etc).

Try one or all of the following:

- Use BeginDeferWindowPos/DeferWindowPos/EndDeferWindowPos functions to move the children.
- Set the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style flag in the dialog.
- Set the WS_EX_LAYERED extended style flag in the dialog.

Comment: WS_EX_LAYERED style is for double buffering. right?

Comment: Yes, system-provided composition-enabled double buffer.

Comment: Mandatory Raymond Chen link for DeferWindowPos: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/06/436043.aspx

Comment: Also, DeferWindowPos might not work. We need to move *selected* controls on re-size and this function seems to be dependent on upper left co-ordinates of the window which will not change on resize.

Comment: @Don Reba,  Thanks for the link. So, changing the x and y accordingly on re-size should work. right? I previously thought its about the xy of parent window. Thanks!

Comment: No, that's WS_EX_COMPOSITED.

Comment: @Hans Passant, oh! didn't know that one. It looks like WS_EX_COMPOSITED is for compositing parent/child windows, while WS_EX_LAYERED is for compositing top-level windows with each other. Worth a try in the original problem.

Comment: But WS_EX_COMPOSITED is not supported in Windows 2000.  My application needs to be compatible with Win2k :(

Answer (score 3):

Simple fixes are:

- creating the slow window last so that it doesn't hold up drawing of the simple controls
- turning on the WS_EX_COMPOSITED style flag so Windows double-buffers the entire window, including its children.  Beware of painting artifacts
- turning off the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style flag so the holes are not so noticeable.  Making the background white would accomplish the same
- keeping the drawing of slow controls simple between WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE and WM_EXITSIZEMOVE
- using less controls, burning up an expensive window on a simple string or image is unnecessary