# Move Multiple Windows Simultaneously - DeferWindowPos

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, scroll, pinvoke

I need to move several external application windows at the same time (together) as a group to simulate scrolling functionality.

If your first thought is "why would you want to do that" or "you should never do that", just pretend that it's a good idea and would be fantastic.

So far I have tried the PInvoke methods [MoveWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MoveWindow.html), [SetWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html), and (BeginDeferWindowPos, [DeferWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/DeferWindowPos.html), EndDeferWindowPos).

All of these methods produce about the same performance. Moving one window is super snappy, two windows is no big deal, but once I try to move three or more windows things start to get ugly. Here is a snippet using the deferred method to show you how I am doing things and keeping track of performance.

```csh
private void multiMoveWindows(int moveAmt, int startingIndex)
{
    int tempX;
    int howmanyTimes = 0;
    int numOfWidgetsToMove = 0;
    int moveAmtRemaining = moveAmt;
    IntPtr MultiWindowStructure;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();            
    WidgetTracker[] tmp_WhichWidgets = new WidgetTracker[10];           

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, WidgetTracker> entry in m_dictWT)
    {
        WidgetTracker tmp = new WidgetTracker();
        tmp = entry.Value;
        if (tmp.WIndex >= startingIndex)
        {
            tmp_WhichWidgets[numOfWidgetsToMove] = tmp;
            ++numOfWidgetsToMove;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < moveAmtRemaining; i++)  
    {
    MultiWindowStructure = Native_Methods.BeginDeferWindowPos(numOfWidgetsToMove);
        foreach (WidgetTracker tmp in tmp_WhichWidgets)
        {
            if (tmp != null)
            {
                tmp.surveilWidget();
                tempX = tmp.WidgetRectLeft - 1;                    
                MultiWindowStructure = Native_Methods.DeferWindowPos(
                    MultiWindowStructure, tmp.WidgetHandle, HWND.NOTOPMOST, tempX, tmp.WidgetRectTop, 0, 0, SWP.NOREDRAW | SWP.NOZORDER | SWP.NOACTIVATE | SWP.NOSIZE);
                howmanyTimes++;
            }
        }
        t.Start();
        Native_Methods.EndDeferWindowPos(MultiWindowStructure);
        t.Stop();             
    }
    MessageBox.Show(howmanyTimes.ToString() + " move requests made." + Environment.NewLine + 
        "Execution of EndDeferWindowPos took " + t.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + " sec " + t.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + " ms." );    
}
```

And here is the result for moving 4 windows, 320px left, 1px at a time:
[image]

<s>As you can imagine, waiting 14.5 seconds to see 4 windows make their way across the screen 320 pixels is painful to watch.</s>

<sup>I've added a few SWP flags and improved performance, but 7.5 seconds is still not workable.</sup>

## -    **How can this be accomplished in a fluid manner?**

Yes, I realize that I can move more than 1px at a time, but that won't resolve the underlying issue. The way I understand it, using any of the PInvoke methods to move windows posts messages to the WinAPI message pump (WndProc()) and waits for the message to be closed / caught / handled before posting the next message. I think this is where I am spending that 14.5 seconds - waiting for messages to be handled.

I have tried using SWP ASYNCWINDOWPOS and the result is horrendous. Each window only gets a few dozen of the messages seemingly at random so that windows are overlapping and as a whole the train barely moves.

The closest I've come to a solution is to assign each "widget" a parent (for example a WindowsFormsHost + an MDI window) and putting them in a form/window and then scrolling that form/window. However I have several reasons for not wanting to do that.

#### Please help!

*Update: Further information available on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/714960/Move-Multiple-Windows-Simultaneously) where I have duplicated this question.*

---

### Update

Adding SWP flags helped a lot but what I determined to actually be slowing things down so much was my test application. Moving 4 of these WPF windows at a time I got it down to about 8.5 seconds.

[image: sorry for the annoying flicker, first time using Cropper...]

When I changed out my test window for a standard empty notepad, that dropped to 0.6 seconds which would be okay for my purposes. Therefore I'm pretty confident that the code is sound. So then the question becomes, **how to minimize window flicker** when implementing this code with a time-dependent move-offset (controlled motion) routine.
This is still a work in progress so I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Another idea might be to snapshot the widgets in a bitmap, hide the widgets, scroll the bitmap, and then reshow the widgets. This assumes that the relative positions of the widgets does not change.

Comment: Also, assigning the widgets a temporary parent and scrolling the parent is still possibly the fastest solution because you get Windows to do all the work.

Comment: I think I may have to go with your first suggestion to make sure I get reliable performance.

Comment: In the end, I had to make Windows "do all the work" by scrolling parent elements. You can see the results for yourself here: https://www.myokuma.com/osp-widget-manager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953060/avoid-flickering-on-a-dialog-that-moves-its-controls-on-resize

Comment: @WernerHenze This project has no control over the content of windows / controls to be moved such as the dialog box mentioned in that question.